# how to use angularjs based template in meanjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs

I am really new to meanjs. I have learnt how to create a basic module and how to write the client and server side of it. But I need a dashboard for the app. I can't figure out how to use the angularjs dashboard in a meanjs application. 
If you know of any tutorials or can give me tips on how to do this, that would be really helpful. 
If you can provide an example by picking any angularjs admin template online and showing how to plug it into the meanjs application, that would be awesome.

Comment: You can have an subdomain dashboard connected to your main App-API.
For exemple: http://akveo.com/blur-admin/#/dashboard

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I general - try to use Stack Overflow for code-specific questions. More general questions like this belong in other StackExchange forums like Programmers or something similar.

In general, though, Angular is just a vehicle for building things like dashboards - so try to google Angular-specific dashboard plugins that give you directives to feed your data into.

Good luck!

Comment: @Wandrille Thanks for the reply. Can you please provide a reference on how to create a subdomain in meanjs?

Comment: Dont lose time with that now. Work offline with 2 distinct app. And when you will deploy your app online, you have options to create the subdomain with your host service